# Show all post content in dotnetnuke blog module

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm got a website with the DNN blog module.  Almost all of the posts have images in them, but on the standard view of the posts they're all listed out with none of the html content and simply a "read more" link at the bottom of the post.  Is there a way to display the full post content as you would see in the details view?

Comment: So I didn't find an automatic way to do this, but if you copy the post into the summary it will work like it's supposed to.  To ensure you remember this, you can set make entry summary mandatory in the blog module settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the Ultimate DNN Blog Module - [SunBlogNuke](http://sunblognuke.com), which supports the option "ShowAll in the EntryList" for some specific entries or all the entries. I thought that this handy option should fit your requirement. Hope it makes sense.

BTW, you can try out the demo website here - demo.sunblognuke.com.